# how to mix a win xp computer and 3 win 7 computers in a lan

Tags: networking, router

I have a new router Netgear R8000 and is connected to a Windows XP computer. I cannot seem to connect it (router and Windows XP computer) to 3 other Windows 7 computers. Should I be using a homegroup or workgroup or something else - I am a bit lost.

Comment: The question is a bit obscure: how are you trying to connect and what do you want to achieve? What have you done so far and what problem have you run into? Usually you setup all your machines with the same workgroup (default is WORKGROUP).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach might be to set specific folders or other resources as shared. This works cross all versions of Windows from at least XP through 10. The disadvantage is that the password for each machine must be be used, though Windows will remember that password on next access.

- [Turn on file sharing, if it's not on.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304040/how-to-use-the-simple-file-sharing-feature-to-share-files-in-windows-xp)
- In Windows Explorer, right-click a folder and select *Properties*.
- On the *Sharing* tab, select *Advanced Sharing* and set attributes as you wish.
- To access the folder from another machine, either find it in *Network* or create a shortcut to the folder, e.g.

> \\MyOtherPC\FolderName

See also [this MS information](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/file_srv_create_share.mspx).